# c++ pthread multithreading for 2 x Intel Xeon X5570, quad-core CPUs on Amazan EC2 HPC ubuntu instance

Tags: c++, multithreading, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, pthreads

I wrote a program that employs multithreading for parallel computing. I have verified that on my system (OS X) it maxes out both cores simultaneously. I just ported it to Ubuntu with no modifications needed, because I coded it with that platform in mind. In particular, I am running the Canonical HVM Oneiric image on an an Amazon EC2, cluster compute 4x large instance. Those machines feature 2 Intel Xeon X5570, quad-core CPUs.

Unfortunately, my program does not accomplish multithreading on the EC2 machine. Running more than 1 thread actually slows the computing marginally for each additional thread. Running top while my program is running shows that when more than 1 thread is initialized, the system% of CPU consumption is roughly proportional to the number of threads. With only 1 thread, %sy is ~0.1. In either case user% never goes above ~9%.

The following are the threading-relevant sections of my code

```
const int NUM_THREADS = N;    //where changing N is how I set the # of threads

void Threading::Setup_Threading()
{
    sem_unlink("producer_gate");
    sem_unlink("consumer_gate");
    producer_gate = sem_open("producer_gate", O_CREAT, 0700, 0);           
    consumer_gate = sem_open("consumer_gate", O_CREAT, 0700, 0);
    completed   = 0;
    queued      = 0;            

    pthread_attr_init (&attr);
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate (&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);
}

void Threading::Init_Threads(vector <NetClass> * p_Pop)
{

    thread_list.assign(NUM_THREADS, pthread_t());        
    for(int q=0; q<NUM_THREADS; q++)
        pthread_create(&thread_list[q], &attr, Consumer, (void*) p_Pop );
}

void* Consumer(void* argument)
{

    std::vector <NetClass>* p_v_Pop = (std::vector <NetClass>*) argument ;

    while(1)
    {
        sem_wait(consumer_gate);
        pthread_mutex_lock (&access_queued);
        int index = queued;                         
        queued--;
        pthread_mutex_unlock (&access_queued);

        Run_Gen(  (*p_v_Pop)[index-1] );

        completed--;
        if(!completed)                  
            sem_post(producer_gate);
    }
}

main()
{
    ...
    t1 = time(NULL);
    threads.Init_Threads(p_Pop_m);
    for(int w = 0; w < MONTC_NUM_TRIALS ; w++)
    {
        queued = MONTC_POP;
        completed = MONTC_POP;

        for(int q = MONTC_POP-1 ; q > -1; q--) 
            sem_post(consumer_gate);

        sem_wait(producer_gate);

    }
    threads.Close_Threads();
    t2 = time(NULL);
    cout << difftime(t2, t1);
    ...
}
```

Comment: maybe this happens because EC2 cores are virtual cores not real metal solid ones

Comment: Can you give minimal source, that can be compiled?

Comment: @user1034749 Ive spent hours since you posted this trying to isolate the problem code and I've still got a ways until I narrow it all the way. What I have determined though is that it depends on what 'work' gets called in `Consumer()`. I replaced `Run_Gen` with a dummy function that just loops to waste time and then threading worked as designed. There's a ton of stuff that happens in `Run_Gen` (hence the difficulties) but none of it is very special, just vectors and arithmetic. Any thoughts on what could be happening, at least in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, just guess. There is simple way to transform your parallel code to consecutive. For example:

```
thread_func:
   while (1) {
     pthread_mutex_lock(m1);
     //do something
     pthread_mutex_unlock(m1);
     ...
     pthread_mutex_lock(mN);
     pthread_mutex_unlock(mN);
```

If you run such code in several thread, you will not see any speedup, because of mutex usage. Code will work as consecutive, not as parallel. Only one thread will work at any moment.

The bad thing, that you can not used any mutex in your program explicity, but still have such situation. For example, call of "malloc" may cause usage of mutex some where in "C" runtime, call of "write" may cause usage of  mutex somewhere in Linux kernel. Even call of gettimeofday may cause mutex lock/unlock (and they cause, if tell about Linux/glibc).

You may have only one mutex, but spend under it a lot of time, and this may cause such behaviour.

And because of mutex may be used somewhere in kernel and C/C++ runtime, you can see different behaviour with different OSes.

Comment: Could `Rand()` be causing usage of a mutex? Because `Rand()` gets called many times inside of `Run_Gen()`. Or maybe `vector_name.push_back();`, `vector_name.assign();`, `vector <type> vector_name(n);`, `vector_name[x]`? Maybe `exp();` from `<cmath>`. Those are the library function that get called inside `Run_Gen`. There are no mutexes used explicity in my code except for in `Consumer()`, and I think we can rule that out.

Comment: push_back of course can, it use some memory allocator, if capicity not enough. Although normaly there several memory pools per core or some similar mechanizm, but may be runtime is not the up to date. You can check that by running "strace" on your program. And then grep "futex" in strace log.

Comment: And rand on linux uses mutex, you can look at source code of glibc: glibc/stdlib/rand.c: rand->return random(), while random: libc_lock_lock (lock); random_r (&unsafe_state, &retval); libc_lock_unlock (lock);

Comment: Try rand_r, is something changed?

Comment: It worked! I switched to `rand_r()` and adding threads now improves the speed of the program. There still seems to be some inefficiency though. Having 2 threads gives 1.85X speed up, 4 threads -> 3.31X, 6 threads -> 4.84X, 8 threads -> 5.35X. The computer has 8 cores so you can see the returns are diminishing. Could the remaining inefficiency be due to memory allocation with vectors? Anyways, Thanks very much for your help, you saved me many hours this way.

Comment: You can try tcmalloc from google google-perftools. Just build it and preload using LD_PRELOAD mechanizm. If problem in allocator used by std::vector, it should solve problem.

Comment: I will try that. Meanwhile, I tried using strace -f like you said. The only system calls it revealed during the threaded portion of my program were `[pid  2646] mprotect(0x7ffe7c030000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE) = 0`, even when only 1 thread is used. When I run with 6 or more threads I also get some `[pid  2645] mprotect(0x7ffe78030000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE <unfinished ...>` followed immediately by `[pid  2646] <... mprotect resumed> )    = 0`. No Futexes though. Is this significant? Strangley `mprotect`s only show up after 3/5 of the work is done.