# C++ computationaly efficient and threadsafe random function

Tags: c++, multithreading, random

I recently learned [the hard way](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8200272/574733) that `#<cstdlib> rand()` is not thread safe, and on Linux is implemented with mutexes, causing a bottleneck when `rand()` is called frequently by multiple threads. `rand_r` works as a replacement, but there are [concerns](http://www.evanjones.ca/random-thread-safe.html) about the quality of random number generation. Moreover, this situation has caused me to question whether there might be faster random number generators out there, since apparently my code spends a lot of time generating random numbers. There are a few alternatives listed in the link above, but I'm unsure as to their speed and to what other alternatives might be out there.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you don't need any statistical control *across* threads, just use the facilities provided by `<random>`:

```
#include <random>

typedef std:::mt19937 rng_type;
std::uniform_int_distribution<rng_type::result_type> udist(0, 200);

int main()  // this can be per thread!
{
  rng_type rng;

  // seed rng first:
  rng_type::result_type const seedval = get_seed();
  rng.seed(seedval);

  rng_type::result_type random_number = udist(rng);

  return random_number;
}
```

The Mersenne twister PRNG is both fast and has good statistical properties. Maintaining a separate (and separately seeded) engine object in each thread you avoid all concurrency issues.

Comment: @Kerrek does `<random>` use a Mersenne twister? And how does its speed compare to `rand()`. Also how are new random numbers acquired here? can i just repeatedly do `= random_number`, or do I have to do `random_number = udist(rng);` each time?

Comment: @MattMunson: `std::mt19937` is a particular Mersenne twister. `rand()` isn't definite, but usually it's a linear congruential rng. LC is fast, but MT has much better statistical properties and is also fast. Anyway, browse the docs for `<random>`, you have a whole choice of engines. It'll also show you how to use them; usually best through distributions as in my example (though you could also call the naked engine if you wanted to).

Comment: @Matt: you can also `auto f = std::bind(udist, rng)` and get a function that produces a new random number each time you call it like `f()`.

Answer (score 2):

In Linux, you can read from [/dev/urandom](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man4/random.4.html) in a nonblocking way.

Comment: You should never use the system's entropy sources for *large* amounts of randomness. `urandom` is great for seeding, but not for persistent random number generation. It doesn't even have a definite distribution as far as I know.